# need executing bag_to_pcd: broken packages on Ubuntu 10.4 (Lucid)

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, bag-to-pcd, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

my final aim is simply to convert a .bag file to .pcd I found out that there is a simple command for that:

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd
```

for that I need ros installed, I followed the tutorial instructions, but running

```
apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
```

it found many broken packages

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  ros-electric-desktop-full: Depends: ros-electric-eigen (= 1.6.0-s1323552432~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-tutorials (= 0.1.3-s1323570867~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1323552462~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-slam-gmapping (= 1.2.4-s1323564969~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-stage (= 1.4.1-s1323569881~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-visualization (= 1.6.7-s1323558747~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.9-s1323553146~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-perception-pcl (= 1.0.2-s1323553637~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-experimental (= 0.2.2-s1323566592~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.4-s1323553467~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-gazebo (= 1.4.9-s1323566768~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-simulator-stage (= 1.4.0-s1323570009~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry-visualization (= 0.1.1-s1323587798~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-common-tutorials (= 0.1.2-s1323588081~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1323553224~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-robot-model (= 1.6.3-s1323555199~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-visualization-tutorials (= 0.2.3-s1323589393~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-geometry (= 1.6.1-s1323552584~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-laser-pipeline (= 1.2.0-s1323557302~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-navigation (= 1.6.5-s1323562415~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

so I installed just ros-electric-ros-base but that didn't contain pcl_ros package which I need. I tried installing ros-electric-perception-pcl because I thought that it's going to have pcl_ros inside but I got another broken packages report.

Can you help me with this, what should I try? Different linux dist to install ros, or convert bag to pcd differently?

Thanks a lot,

Michal

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12657/need-executing-bag_to_pcd:-broken-packages-on-ubuntu-10.4-(lucid)/) by [Michal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1655/michal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem for me was really a newer version of libeigen3-dev installed on my computer.

Using "sudo aptitude install ros-electric-desktop-all" instead of ..apt-get.. resolved the problem since aptitude worked out that it needs to downgrade libeigen3-dev and did it.

thanks a lot

---

Originally posted by [Michal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1655/michal/) with karma: 36 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct that `ros-electric-perception-pcl` does contain the `pcl_ros` package with the `bag_to_pcd` tool. What you are doing should work.

Since it does not, there is probably some simple mis-configuration. Please check your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list`, and make sure it contains "`deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lucid main`". Then, check all the other steps in the [Ubuntu install instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1655/michal/) on 2012-01-19**:
Thanks for suggestions. I went through all the installation steps again and I still believe there is a problem with libeigen3-dev where I have newer version and it's somehow not compatible.